# How to make docker containers host-agnostic

Tags: networking, docker

I want to have this configuration:

```
                   webcontainer1
                  /
                 /
haproxy_container 
                 \ 
                  \
                   webcontainer2
```

All three components are docker containers.
Yes, I can --link them, and put container names into haproxy configuration, and everything works, provided all 3 are on the same host.

But then, I want to be able to move my webcontainers to other hosts, as needed, *without having to change configuration of haproxy.*

In other words, I want my configuration to be agnostic to where my web containers are running: same host or not, I want them to be simply pingable by name.

How to do that?

P.S. I know how to forward ports from container to host, and I understand that I could replace names of my webcontainers with names of the hosts I would move them to - this does not qualify as an answer.

The goal is to have freedom to move things around without changing any configs.

Answer (score 0):

I run most of my dockerized services tied to own static ips using the next approach:

1. I create ip aliases for all services on docker host
2. Then I run each service redirecting ports from this ip into container so each service have own static ip which could be used by external users and other containers.
3. All containers use ips or domain names for access to other containers.

Now I could move container (with ip alias) to any other docker host and all other containers will continue to work with it - no need to touch them.

Sample:

```
docker run --name dns --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.20:53:53/udp dns
docker run --name registry --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.12:80:5000 registry
docker run --name cache --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.13:80:3142 -v /data/cache:/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng cache
docker run --name mirror --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.19:80:80 -v /data/mirror:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro mirror
...
```

Answer to comment (as it too long for comment):

1) correct - I don't need to even know container's ip - I'm using static ip addresses to work with services in containers

2) yes, containers are not pingable, only necessary ports exposed there

3) [ip aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing) are additional ip addresses for single interface.

As necessary ports for each containers mapped to ip alias - I don't need to know anything else about container, I'm just using ip:port (or name:port) to work with it. Additional benefit - I have multiple containers which mapping exposing port 80 in the same host - and I don't need to use proxy or different port: http://service1 and http://service2 are working - as they have different ip addresses (which are aliases and I could have many of them).

Comment: I need some clarification on this. 1) The IPs that you show seem to indicate host interfaces, not IPs assigned to the container, if my reading of the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) is correct   2)  I don't see how your containers could be pingable by container host name, since you don't even assign host name to your containers using --host 3) What do you mean by "I create ip aliases" - I'm not sure I understand this

Comment: @dmitry-z, modified answer, as reply was too long for comment.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show how you create IP aliases, in particular-how do you pick IP numbers

Comment: It depends on your network. If we are talking about non public addresses - they should be in the same subnet as main ip of the box (so no additional configuration of other boxes required) , but outside of dhcp range to avoid clash. In sample above subnet is 172.16, and 172.16.177 dedicated for docker containers. If your subnet 192.160.0.*, then aliases also should start from 192.160.0

Comment: so you add IP alias in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ (in case of RHEL etc) on host A, then when you want to move your service to host B, you delete these entries from this file in  A, and add them to a file in B - is this correct?

Comment: Ok, I see several issues w this approach. 1) You configure hosts, rather than images, which sort of defeats the purpose of Docker. 2) It will not work at all when you want to move your service to a different availability zone(datacenter) because of different subnet. 3) It depends on controlling DHCP config, which you may not own, and without  it it may cause problems on network 4) You need root - in a large org, this and previous point is a no-go. Still, it's an interesting and clever approach, and I learned a couple of things-so thank you. Feel free to rebut the points above.

Comment: 1) I have not found better apprach 2) use dns names instead of ips in this case 3) you don't need to control dhcp (I don't have dhcp control), just don't use dhcp addresses 4) if you could run docker container - you have full control over the box, even if you are not root - you are root in container and you could access host file system

Comment: 3) How do you know which addresses will not conflict with DHCP config. How do you know the IP range DHCP picks from now,  and what if it changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way of doing this, think about host containers as a subnet. If I understand properly you want to have at least two subnets. You need a way to connect those subnets which means you have to change the default device docker0's subnet. This is what I've tried and works:

1. Stop docker:

   - host 1: `service docker stop`
   - host 2: `service docker stop`
2. Remove the existing MASQUERADE rules from the POSTROUTING chain:

   - host 1: `iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING`
   - host 2: `iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING`
3. Remove existing IP address from the docker bridge:

   - host 1: `ip link set dev docker0 down && ip addr del 172.17.42.1/16 dev docker0`
   - host 2: `ip link set dev docker0 down && ip addr del 172.17.42.1/16 dev docker0`
4. Pick a subnet:

   - host 1: `ip addr add 192.168.3.1/24 dev docker0 && ip link set dev docker0 up && ip addr show docker0`
   - host 2: `ip addr add 192.168.4.1/24 dev docker0 && ip link set dev docker0 up && ip addr show docker0`
5. Start docker:

   - host 1: `service docker start`
   - host 2: `service docker start`
6. Verify the POSTROUTING chain was updated with the MASQUERADE rule for your new subnet:

   - host 1: `iptables -t nat -L -n`
   - host 2: `iptables -t nat -L -n`
7. Connect the two hosts subnets:

   - host 1: `ip route add 192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.1.2 dev eth0`
   - host 2: `ip route add 192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.1.3 dev eth0`
8. Use [serf](https://www.serfdom.io/) to create a cluster:

   - host 1: `serf agent`
   - webcontainer1: `serf agent -h=webcontainer1`
   - host 2: `serf agent`
   - webcontainer2: `serf agent -h=webcontainer2`
   - haproxy1: `serf agent -h=haproxy1`
9. haproxy, you can use the following script to update /etc/hosts with ips of the hosts. With serf, you can not a join the cluster with duplicate names:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

updatehosts()
{
  sed -i 's/.\+# serf//' /etc/hosts
  serf members | sed 's/:.\+$//g' | grep -v `hostname` | awk '{ print $2 " " $1 " # serf" }' >> /etc/hosts
}

case "${SERF_EVENT}" in
  member-join)
    updatehosts
    ;;
  member-leave)
    updatehosts
    ;;
  member-failed)
    updatehosts
    ;;
esac
```

The only part I see where you end up configuring hosts instead of containers is the subnet part but you can also do that in a container with right privileges.

I hope that helps